# SQL Server Express connection string error when site moved to 3rd party hosting

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I created an ASP.NET MVC 5 site locally that uses Identity. I eventually moved the connection string to point to a SQL Server on a 3rd party hosting server and all worked well. I then setup the site and published to the hosting server and now I keep getting a network related error.

The connection string specifies a local SQL Server Express instance using a database location within the application's `App_Data` directory.

Initially I did have a local SQL Server Express file in my `App_Data` folder but since I moved the connection string to point to SQL Server I deleted the `.mdf` files from the `App_Data` folder and the folder is empty on my hosting companies server.

The initial connection string was called `DefaultConnection`, I have it commented out in my `web.config` file. That connection does try to use a SQL Server Express but it shouldn't be being used. I've also searched my whole site for `DefaultConnection` and it does not find anything.

Looking for any suggestions.

Here is the `web.config` file. The `DefaulConnection` section is commented out but I left it in the config file in case I needed it. My SQL Server connection is `DbConnection`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <!--<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DELL960\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NTCC;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />-->
        <add name="DbConnection" 
             connectionString="Data Source=XX.XX.XX.XXX;Initial Catalog=northtxc_web;Integrated Security=False;User ID=northtxc_txsqladmin;Password=**********;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <trust level="Full" />
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
        <roleManager enabled="true" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules>
            <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
        </modules>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>  
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly> 
               <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
               <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly>
               <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
               <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
          <dependentAssembly> 
              <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc"   publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
              <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.4.0" newVersion="5.2.4.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

**UPDATE**

If I add any `.mdf` file into the `App_Data` folder, I get past the error about SQL Server Express. However I then get an error with the RoleManger. I'm guessing that it still looking at a connection for SQL Server Express somewhere, now that it's not trying to create the SQL Server Express file it's trying to access it for the RoleManager?

This is where I get my error:

```
@if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
```

Comment: You need to update the connection string used by the default RoleProvider. The MSDN has an example you can follow, assuming you're using the same provider: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/ms164661(v=vs.80)#example

Comment: @Tieson...that wasn't it for me but using a piece from that link lead me to a different error which lead me to the fix. So, ultimately your post did point me in the right direction. Thanks!